# Having trouble with my horizontal scroll - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope you are doing well today. I'm having an issue with this horizontal scroll in flutter. The images are supposed to scroll left and right and depending on the picture, you will press the button and have the ability to guess the type of pic. For some reason, images and tags don't match with images. The image names are linked to the vehicleNames list in _MyHomePageState. I have also included image_card.dart to show how ImageCard works. Thank you for the second set of eyes.

main.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'image_card.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Guess the car!'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  String curVehName = "";
  double scrollPercent = 0.0;
  Offset startDrag;
  double startDragPercentScroll;
  double finishScrollStart;
  double finishScrollEnd;
  AnimationController finishScrollController;

  List<String> vehicleNames = [
    'bmw',
    'ford',
    'rover',
    'toyota'
  ];

  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    finishScrollController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() { 
      setState(() {
        scrollPercent = lerpDouble(finishScrollStart, finishScrollEnd,
            finishScrollController.value);
      });
    });

    @override
    dispose(){
      finishScrollController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

  List<Widget> buildCards(){
    List<Widget> cardList = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < vehicleNames.length;i++){
      cardList.add(buildCard(i,scrollPercent));
      print("index: ${i}");
    }
    return cardList;
  }

  Widget buildCard(int cardIndex, double scrollPercent){

    final cardScrollPercent = scrollPercent / ( 1 / vehicleNames.length);

    return FractionalTranslation(
      translation: Offset(cardIndex-cardScrollPercent,0.0),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ImageCard(imageName: vehicleNames[cardIndex],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  onHorizontalDragStart(DragStartDetails details){
    startDrag = details.globalPosition;
    startDragPercentScroll = scrollPercent;
  }

  onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details){
    final currentDrag = details.globalPosition;
    final dragDistance = currentDrag.dx - startDrag.dx;
    final singleCardDragPercent = dragDistance / context.size.width;

    setState(() {
      scrollPercent = ( startDragPercentScroll + ( -singleCardDragPercent
          / vehicleNames.length)).clamp(0.0, 1.0-(1/vehicleNames.length));
    });
  }

  onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details){
    finishScrollStart = scrollPercent;
    finishScrollEnd = (scrollPercent * vehicleNames.length).round()
        /vehicleNames.length;

    finishScrollController.forward(from: 0.0);

    setState(() {
      startDrag = null;
      startDragPercentScroll = null;
      curVehName = '';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onHorizontalDragStart: onHorizontalDragStart,
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: onHorizontalDragUpdate,
              onHorizontalDragEnd: onHorizontalDragEnd,
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent ,
              child: Stack(
                children: buildCards(),
              ),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: (){
                setState((){
                  this.curVehName = vehicleNames[(scrollPercent*10).round()];
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                  'Show Answer',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 4.0,
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              highlightedBorderColor: Colors.black,
            ),
            Text(
              curVehName,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.blue,
                letterSpacing: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

image_card.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageCard extends StatelessWidget{

  final String imageName;

  ImageCard({this.imageName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 4.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/$imageName.jpg',
          height: 300,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue. It seems that the

```
this.curVehName = vehicleNames[(scrollPercent*10).round()];
```

hard-coded the value of numbers needed in my vehicle names list. Once I added 10 pictures and added names to the list, it then worked as directed. The goal now is to see if I can make this a dynamic list.